# Does every compactification have an extension property?

Tags: general-topology, compactification

A pair (Y, f) is a compactification of a topological space X iff for every compact space X' and continous map g from X to X', there is a continuous map g' from Y to X' such that g'(f(x))=g(x) for all x in X. Is this true?

Answer (score 3):

No. For example, the one point compactification of $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to the circle $S^1$. Another compactification of $(0,1)$ is $[0,1]$. But there is no continuous map $S^1\to [0,1]$ which extends the map $(0,1)\to S^1$.

The Stone–Čech compactification is a special compactification which satisfies your condition when $X'$ is additionally assumed to be Hausdorff. Moreover, the map $g'$ is unique in this case. This is the *universal property* of the Stone–Čech compactification.

This raises an interesting question that I don't know the answer to off the top of my head: can other compactifications be characterized in terms of universal properties?

Comment: The one point compactification has a characterization: let $X \to (Y,y_0)$ be proper on $Y \setminus \{y_0\}$ and $Y$ compact, hausdorff. Then there is a based map $X^* \to Y$ that extends $f$. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/one-point+compactification

Comment: I guess it's not quite as natural! Apparently Bohr compactification also has a univeral property.

Comment: I have read somewhere that if a continuous map f from X to a compact space Y has a universal property, then f is an embedding and f(X) is a dense subspace of Y. Please help with this part. I am able to prove denseness only after assuming that f is surjective. I know it's not right.

Comment: @Percy That's a different question, so you should post a new question. Please include context, like the source where you found the statement.

Comment: @Alex.  Isn't it the converse of the original question? I got an answer that the forward way doesn't always hold unless there are extra conditions such as Hausdorff.  What about the other way?